# How to make google requests through TOR?

Tags: python, urllib2, tor, socks

I'm trying to make some requests on Google for some keywords.
Below is the code I'm using :

```
import socks
import socket
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
import urllib2

print(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.%s/search?q=%s&hl=%s&pws=0&as_qdr=all&gl=%s&num=%s" % (
            'fr', 'python', 'fr', 'fr', '10')).read()) # All requests will now pass through the SOCKS proxy
```

However I get the following traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/tor.py", line 8, in <module>
    'fr', 'python', 'fr', 'fr', '10')).read()) # All requests will now pass through the SOCKS proxy
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 1194, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\httplib.py", line 1053, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\httplib.py", line 1093, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\httplib.py", line 1049, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\httplib.py", line 893, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\httplib.py", line 855, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\httplib.py", line 832, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\socket.py", line 566, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 687, in connect
    raise ProxyConnectionError(msg, error)
socks.ProxyConnectionError: Error connecting to SOCKS5 proxy 127.0.0.1:9050: [Errno 10061] Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée
```

I suppose I didn't configure something but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Hi there!  It would help if you translated the error message at the bottom from French to English

Comment: [**`WSAECONNREFUSED
10061`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx#WSAECONNREFUSED) *Connection refused. No connection could be made because the target computer actively refused it. This usually results from trying to connect to a service that is inactive on the foreign host—that is, one with no server application running*

Comment: You're not running a tor client. There's nothing listening on the SOCKS port.

Comment: FYI, there will be captchas on Google most of the time when you're using Tor, since there are so many requests to Google's servers originating from the same address.